# Ruby on Rails: File.delete does not delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delete-file

I have an issue with deleting files in my Rails App. On a button I call an action `delete_results` in which some files should be deleted if they exist. Somehow, everything else in the action is working (for example the `flash:success`), but the files are just not deleted. In the console the line works fine. Here's a small example:

```
def delete_results
   File.delete("MyFile.txt") if File.exist?("MyFile.txt")

   somemodel = Somemodel.first
   if somemodel.update_attributes(:attr1 => nil, :attr2 => nil)
      somemodel.save
      flash[:success] = "The results are deleted!"
      redirect_to root_path
   else 
      render 'somepage'
   end
end
```

Since the action can only be called by the admin, I can't think of any access right problems. The files that should be deleted are in the main app directory. Is there any major mistake in my code or do I have to include something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get if you log `File.exist?` in that method? (You can use `puts`, `Rails.logger`, or add a debugging statement to check this)

Comment: Could you explain how exactly I can use `puts`or `Rails.logger`? Somehow I can't let anything show up - even in the terminal where I started the server there is nothing happening when using that button...

Comment: See section 3 on byebug [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html). Setup byebug and see if your rails app runs delete_results how you think it does. It sounds like the first step will be verifying that the method runs in the first place. Once you've done that, I'd suggest then checking if your `File.exist?` call returns `true`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! :)  The method does run and the File does exist. If I call `File.delete` in the byebug-environment, the file is deleted...

Comment: No problem :) That is interesting... I'm afraid there's not a lot I can do to help with that, only give some advice. I'd suggest verifying 100% that what you're running in byebug is exactly the same (is the file deleted if you step through the code or only if you run it yourself?). 

Secondly, try to isolate the problem. See how much code you can strip out with the issue persisting, or before it suddenly works. That'll help you identify where you've gone wrong. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to your help and byebug I discovered that the mistake was not in the `File.delete`, but due to the `redirect_to` -- somehow that disturbed deleting the files... Thank you very, very much for your help! :)

Comment: Ah! Nice one. Glad you could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `redirect_to` disturbed deleting the files  --  using `'render'` instead worked and now the files do get deleted :)